# mysql count() row entries per column above 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a total rating query and part of it  requires
    **$sel = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8)/XXXX as total FROM ratings WHERE shop_id = $shop_id");**

Where XXXX is i need to count the number of row entries per column above 0, and divide the TOTAL by # to get total rating.

math is:
total / number of values above 0

thanks

I am trying to count the number of entries above 0,  which means for shop_id of 1 has a total of 35.
35 is divided by number of entries above 0 which is 5 to get total result not taking the 0 rows/column as a vote.

This is my desired output related to the data in the table.
    shop_id 1 -> 35/7 = 5
    shop_id 2 -> 42/  = 3
    shop_id 3 -> 40/8 = 5

[image]

Comment: Very ambiguous.  Sample data and desired output might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
SUM(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8)/
SUM(IF(col1 > 0, 1, 0), IF(col2 > 0, 1, 0), ... ) AS total 
FROM ratings 
WHERE shop_id = $shop_id")
```

Replacing `...` with the same logic for each column you're testing. The sum will essentially serve the same purpose as a count since you're conditionally outputting zero or one.

Don't quote me on the syntax - but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Tried this but keeping an error, "arning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"
no syntax errors are showing in my code to indicate syntax problems.

Comment: It might be best if you can run the SQL outside of your PHP script, maybe command line or PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: just ran my query in hiediSQL:


SELECT SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience + bud_quality + bud_price + drink_price + space_cake + accessibility + toilet_access)/24 as total FROM ratings WHERE shop_id = 1    

is the exact code am using, 24 is the number of field values above 0. Which is divided across 2 rows(with matching shop_id) and 12 columns which make up the total vote. I need the number 24 to change depending on votes. fiddling with count() but very lost, thanks

Comment: could you explain what the code you gave me is doing exactly.

I think i know what i need to happen now, just can't make it happen

Comment: Each `IF(col1 > 0, 1, 0)` says "If the column's value is greater than zero, provide a value of 1, otherwise a value of zero". Once you do that check for each column, you'll wind up with a series of zeros and ones that you'll sum together. `SUM(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)` for instance, will essentially provide you with a count of columns with a value greater than zero, per row.